# Apply Blinking border to a tableview in appcelerator

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have a doubt in appcelerator. Does any body know how to apply a blinking border to a table view in appcelerator. I applied a border color to tableview, but i need to blinking it with other color. Any help will be deeply appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using javascript setInterval.

```
setInterval(function() {
    if (table.borderColor == '#F00') {
        table.borderColor = '#0F0';
    }
    else {
        table.borderColor = '#F00';
    }
}, 500);
```

First set a borderColor in tableView and interchenge it with other color with setInterval(). set the time in milisecond as how first you want it to blink.

Comment: how do we stop this blinking after a button click ??? it would be so helpful if u can reply to this

Comment: Hi sharif, how about the same case in the view ? i tried to implement, but it didnt work. do u have any idea ?

Comment: This should work for view:  Ti.UI.backgroundColor = 'white';
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var view = Titanium.UI.createView({
   borderRadius:10,
   borderWidth :10,
   borderColor :'#F00',
   width:400,
   height:400
});

setInterval(function() {
if (view.borderColor == '#F00') {
view.borderColor = '#0F0';
}
else {
view.borderColor = '#F00';
}
}, 800);

win.add(view);
win.open();

Comment: For stopping the blinking you should define this function in your app 

         function myStopFunction() {
            clearInterval(myVar);
         }
and call the myStopFunction() in the button event. Make sure setInterval is assign to variable myVar.