# Apply Blinking border to a view in appcelerator

Tags: javascript, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

Does anybody knows how to apply blinking effect to a view in appcelerator ?. It works fine for me in the case of table view. But didn't get the blinking in the case of applying same code in view. Does anybody have any idea ? Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Some test code would be helpful. Also, I know of no view property for `blinking`, not even for tableView for that matter. So you may be facing a custom function solution.

Comment: Did you check the solution for view I provided in your previous post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35123808/apply-blinking-border-to-a-tableview-in-appcelerator/35128637?noredirect=1#comment58024357_35128637 ?

Comment: yes..it works perfect for tableview. i put those code inside $.test.addEventListener('load', function(e){ }. so it works fine. but in my current working file, there is no event like this. is that the problem it's not blinking ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the code

```
Ti.UI.backgroundColor = 'white';
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var view = Titanium.UI.createView({
borderRadius : 10,
borderWidth : 10,
borderColor : '#F00',
width : 400,
height : 400
});

setInterval(function() {
if (view.borderColor == '#F00') {
    view.borderColor = '#0F0';
} else {
    view.borderColor = '#F00';
}
}, 500);


win.add(view);
win.open();
```